# Firebase-hosting can't get to api routes node

Tags: node.js, firebase, express, google-cloud-functions, firebase-hosting

I have a route for '/' but it serves the public html index file instead, I tried changing the root directory of my api to /api/** but it gives me a 404 error.
it works quiet well when I run it locally but when I deploy it I run into the issue of only having the index.html file.
here is the **firebase.json** file

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "public",
    "rewrites":[
      {
        "source":"/api/**",
        "functions":"app"
      }
    ],
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ]
  }
}
```

and the **index.js** folder

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions')
const express = require('express')
\\.
\\.
\\requiring routes and middleware
app.use(helmet())
app.use(express.json())
app.use(cookieParser())
app.use(cors({
    origin:"*",
    credentials:true
}))

app.get('/',(req,res)=>{
    res.status(200).send("works");
})
app.use(locationActions)
app.use(filterActions)
app.use('/auth',userAuth)
app.use('/adm',AdminRoutes)
app.use('/prod',prodActions)
app.use('/user',userActions)


exports.app = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

Comment: Which URL are you accessing that doesn't work the way you expect?  What you have configured now will only rewrite URLs with a path prefix of "/api" to your function.

Comment: https://uiniquebackend.firebaseapp.com/api/ .. i'm expecting this to give me the works message for i have this line in the app.js file `res.status(200).send("works");`

Comment: --edit--- i changed the '/' to '/api/test/' `app.get('/',(req,res)=>{
    res.status(200).send("works");
})` and still gave me the 404 error not found

Answer (score 0):

.send() doesn't seem to work quiet well with firebase I just have to say something like response.json({message}), this will actually send the response. also mongoose connection is prohibited as I was using a free account so any connection outside firebase is rejected.